# How can I get cid, and cname for course registered by all students of EEE?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following data. I have three tables Student, Course and StudentCourse

Student( Sid, Sname, Sbranch, Sage)  - This contains the Student ID's, Names, Their respective branch and age. Also there are only branches in college namely CSE, EEE and IT.

StudentCourse( Sid, Cid) - This contains Student ID and Course ID -- this conveys which student registered for which course.

Course( Cid, Cname, CCredits)  - This contains course ID, Course name and number of credits thats course carries. There are total four courses in that semester are offered namely OS, DBMS, CNW and PHY.

How to write a query to get the cid, cname of courses registered by all the students of EEE.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are looking for courses which has no students from the st_branch of 'EEE' registered?

Comment: Actually, i am looking for courses which are registered by all the students of  EEE ?

Comment: Please post what you've tried. Also when responding, _NEVER_ use the words "don't work". Always explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear the structure of your tables but based on your description, you can try something like (change the name of your tables exactly as you have them in your database):

```
select distinct ct.c_name
from student_table st,
student_course sc,
course_table ct
where st.st_branch = 'EEE'
and st.st_id = sc.st_id
and ct.c_id = c_id;
```

Also, it would be good if you post what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here and don't know much of the rules. I tried to run  select distinct ct.c_name
from student_table st,
student_course sc,
course_table ct
where st.st_branch = 'EEE'
and st.st_id = sc.st_id
and ct.c_id = c_id;    ( the Error i got is ORA-00904: "SC"."SID": invalid identifier)

Comment: I also reformatted my question with exact table names as in my database. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select c_id, c_name
from   course c
where  not exists ( 
                    select st_id
                    from   student
                    where  st_branch = 'EEE'
                      and  (st_id, c.c_id) not in (
                                                    select st_id, c_id
                                                    from   student_course
                                                  )
                  )
;
```

Comment: I tried to execute your query and I am getting all the courses list. What i am looking is particular cid and cname of course that are registered by all ( i mean every) students of EEE.

Comment: @Y.SuryaNarayana - I believe the query is correct. It's on you to prove it isn't, by showing a counter-example (a small example of your tables, with data on which you ran this and it gave the wrong result). More likely, you probably **modified** the query, and you modified it incorrectly. (It is almost certain you changed the query, because I see you changed your Original Post - you changed the column names, so you must have done the same in my query.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution might get the result as you expected

```
select distinct
 c.cid, 
 cname,
 from course c
 join StudentCourse sc on c.cid=sc.cid
 join student s on s.sid=sc.sid
 where sbranch='EEE';
```

Comment: It will be great you comment on what your code does.

Comment: Why am I getting, SC and CID as invalid identifiers ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to write a query to get the cid, cname of courses registered by all the students of EEE.

The following filters the students of sbranch = 'EEE', joins up to courses, then uses distinct to get a unique set of courses.

```
  -- Start of test data
  with student(sid, sname, sbranch, sage) as 
       (select 1, 'student1', 'EEE', 19 from dual union all
        select 2, 'student2', 'CSE', 20 from dual union all
        select 3, 'student3', 'IT', 18 from dual),
      studentcourse(sid, cid) as
       (select 1, 1 from dual union all
        select 2, 2 from dual union all
        select 3, 4 from dual),
      course(cid, cname, credits) as 
       (select 1, 'OS', 3 from dual union all
        select 2, 'DBMS', 3 from dual union all
        select 3, 'CNW', 4 from dual union all
        select 4, 'PHY', 5 from dual
        )
  -- End of test data
  -- Beginning of main query
  select distinct crs.cid, crs.cname
  from   course crs
   inner join studentcourse sc on (sc.cid = crs.cid)
   inner join student st on (st.sid = sc.sid)
  where st.sbranch = 'EEE'      ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Cid, Cname
 FROM Course C 
 WHERE Cid NOT IN (SELECT Cid
                    FROM Sudent S CROSS JOIN Course C1 LEFT OUTR JOIN (SELECT Sid, Cid
                                                                        FROM StudentCours) SC 
                                                        ON SC.Sid = S.Sid AND SC.Cid = C1.Cid   
                    WHERE SC.Sid IS NULL AND S.Sbranch = 'EEE')
```

The subquery in barkets returns all the courses that were **not** taken by EEE stuents 
So we need the courses **not** in this list
The key is the `CROSS JOIN` that gives as all the posible course-studet pairs